# How to set that which one will use localhost port

Tags: localhost

I have tried to install WAMP, APPServ
but when i go to http://localhost it go into XAMPP which is previously install on the computer.
how to select that which one i am going to use on localhost.

Comment: You can have only one webserver running on a port. Either remove/deconfigure xammp, or run wamp on a different port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit http.conf file in notepad usually located in C:\wamp\Apache2\conf .

then do either CTL+F or go to EDIT/FIND from the notepad menubar. this will open FIND window.

type 80 in the 'Find What' box and click find next. replace 80 to whichever port to want apache to listen to. 
you may have to change to two or more places depending on your configuration. and then restart your apache server. 
Apache should listen to the port you set in the http.conf file. Hope this helps

Comment: it can not be any port, some ports are restricted and used by other software.

Comment: I didn't meant any restricted port , isn't it that obvious . However, I still apologize for the confusion

Comment: Instead of pointing out flaws in the answer, find a list of restricted ports to improve the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can change the port they work on, by default the its port 80, you can for example set the WAMP to port 8080 and then use to access WAMP: 
    http://localhost:8080
and to access APPServ :
    http://localhost

They will not work at the same default port 80 at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Open C:\xampp\apache\conf, find the httpd.conf file and open with notepad++.
Look for these lines and change 80 in the last line any other port, for example 8080.

```
Listen 8080
```

This way we will be able to run Apache but the http://localhost/url won’t work for that you need to append port number into the URL. For example if you specify Port 8080 in Apache config, you have to specify the URL like this, http://localhost:8080/url.

restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours of searching bc I couldn't access my XAMPP dashboard after changing it's port on httpd CONF file, I realized that if you changed your default port from XAMPP which is 80, you need to mention the new port when searching your localhost on search bar!

So don't forget to search like this:
Http://localhost:your new port