# How to port forward php-built in port number to localhost

Tags: php, localhost, php-builtin-server

PHP has a built-in server that connects to localhost through port 8888. i.e `localhost:8888` I would like to know if it is possible to remove the port number using any port-forwarding method or application, so I can connect to it directly using just `localhost`

Comment: Try browsing the following link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425233/how-to-set-that-which-one-will-use-localhost-port

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you install apache Virtual Hosts. It offers more than the local php development server and is quicker. Or try wamp and xammp

Comment: Apache slows down development runtime.

Comment: If using large amounts of code, it handles requests quicker.